# EntityFramework throwing Error : The table does not have a primary key defined

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am using DatabaseFirst approach in Entity Framework, I am getting Error :

> The table does not have a primary key defined.

Now, when I am Scaffolding for Controller it is giving me

> One or More Entities have Validation Error

Must be because of the EF error has its effect in here.

Earlier, when it was giving me the Primary Key error, I added column in table `StudentAddress` & `StudentCourse` and make it `Primary KEY` just to get rid of the above Error. But added columns are not reflected back in my diagram(*.edmx), though in DB its reflecting back.

DB Script is:

```
create table [Standard](

    StandardID int constraint pk_standard primary key,
    StandardName varchar(255),
    [Description] varchar(255)
);


create table Teacher(
    TeacherID int constraint pk_teacher primary key,
    TeacherName varchar(255),
    StandardID int constraint fk_teacher foreign key references [Standard](StandardID) ,
    TeacherType varchar(255)
);
create table Course(
    CourseID int constraint pk_course primary key,
    CourseName varchar(255),
    Location varchar(255),
    TeacherID int constraint fk_course foreign key references Teacher(TeacherID) ,
);
create table Student(
    StudentID int constraint pk_student primary key,
    StudentName varchar(255),
    StandardID int constraint fk_student foreign key references [Standard](StandardID) ,
);
create table StudentAddress(
    [Id] int constraint pk_SA primary key,
    StudentID int constraint fk_studentaddr foreign key references Student(StudentID) not null,
    Addr1 varchar(255),
    Addr2 varchar(255),
    City varchar (50),
    [State] varchar (50)
);
create table StudentCourse(
    [Index Number] int constraint pk_SC primary key,
    StudentID int constraint fk1_studentcourse foreign key references Student(StudentID) not null,
    CourseID int constraint fk2_studentcourse foreign key references Course(CourseID) not null,
);
```

PS : Creating WebApp using WebApi2 and EF(for data).

Comment: Have you updated your .edmx file since adding the primary keys?  I haven't done DB First in a long time, but you might be able to just right click on your .edmx and choose Update Database, or something to that effect, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @TFrost: I did the same as you or naved mentioned, but still stuck with the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet you didn't define primary keys for `StudentAddress` and `StudentCourse` in the original model. And now, by adding columns to it you change the character of the model significantly.

I think this is what you intended to have:

```sql
create table StudentAddress(
    StudentID int constraint fk_studentaddr foreign key references Student(StudentID) not null,
    Addr1 varchar(255),
    Addr2 varchar(255),
    City varchar (50),
    [State] varchar (50),
    constraint pk_SA primary key (StudentID) -- primary key
);
create table StudentCourse(
    StudentID int constraint fk1_studentcourse foreign key references Student(StudentID) not null,
    CourseID int constraint fk2_studentcourse foreign key references Course(CourseID) not null,
    constraint pk_SC primary key (StudentID, CourseID) -- composite primary key
);
```

This makes `Student-StudentAddress` a `1:1` association and `Student-StudentCourse` a `n:m` association. Thus, `Student-StudentCourse` can be hidden in the class model.

So you should only add primary key *constraints* in stead of *columns*.

Here are the consequences of adding columns:

By adding another column as primary key to `StudentAddress`, the association `Student-StudentAddress` turns into a  `1:n` association (because `StudentAddress.StudentID` can now be duplicated).

With the additional `Index Number` column, `Student-StudentCourse` remains a `n:m` association, but it can no longer be hidden in the class model, because that's only possible if the *junction table* only contains two foreign keys that both comprise a primary key.

I'd create a new edmx from the model above it it suits you. Refreshing the model is probably not going too work well with the modified primary keys.

This is what the edmx should look like after the modifications:

[image]

Comment: Warning still persists in those two tables. And one more, if the table does not have any PK or the table has composite PK, will its Entity Model will not be created ?

Comment: If I create a *new* edmx with your data model and the two tables defined as in my answer, I get no errors. In that case, `StudentCourse` is not part of the class model, `StudentAddress` is.

Comment: Thanks, problem got resolved, was using the wrong DB Context Class.

Answer (score 0):

You should update your model class.

In the Models folder, open the *.edmx file to display the model diagram, Right-click anywhere on the design surface, and select Update Model from Database.

For more information:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/changing-the-database

Comment: I already did that for each table, but nothing happened. Deleted the *.edmx and again added the model but again the same story and same error.

Comment: So,  delete each table from *.edmx file and add them again I think it could be solved.

Comment: I'm really sorry, you got this error when you were trying to scaffold the controllers right? I had this issue before but in EF Code first approach. Simply, I opened my ContextDB class and I commented 'modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(...)' line in OnModelCreating method.  Just this, it worked.